# Win8.1 Someone logged into my PC by adding a new Account

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts

I have just started using win8.1. Yesterday I locked my PC and went to a lecture. Then when I came back, I saw that my lockscreen was changed. I navigated to log-in screen, and saw a different username: XIT (XIT is the abbreviation for my university's IT service. But there should not be any user on my PC named XIT!) Then I switched user, logged into mine, checked user account settings and saw that XIT had admin rights. How can that be possible?

On my PC, there is only one user and that is me. XIT did not install win8.1, I installed it. They control our network, but I do not think that someone from our university's IT, would just crack into my PC for fun. Maybe someone else did it and named the user account after XIT.

What I am wondering is, is there a way to add a new account without logging into my account? Is there a hotkey or something?

Answer (score 2):

Did you set a password for the Administrator account ? 
If someone booted Windows in Safe Mode with the Administrator account they could add a new account without your password. So I suggest that you put a password for the Administrator account too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I set a password for administrator account.

Comment: But I have a question: I am not sure whether administrator acc. was enabled or not. I do not have that option while selecting users. (Do not see a administrator account so that I would log in to.) Even this is the case, can someone login to administrator account?

Comment: Usually the Administrator account is hidden. You can log in as Administrator in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 2):

Are you on a domain? If you're at a university it's quite possible that you are.

On a domain it's possible (unless the admin changes things) for any authorised user to log in on any computer. The user account will be created automatically the first time an authorised user logs on to a computer. Windows domains are designed to work this way: a Domain User is a user that's allowed to log on on to the domain's computers. The alternative (manually creating user accounts on each computer) is too painful to contemplate...

Answer (score 0):

About the Windows login account and password, you still have lots to do. You can set your Windows 8.1 computer to prevent adding a new account and other users from changing your login password. For the consideration of security, learn these.

Comment: Any useful links that you can provide me to learn them? Could not find how to disable adding new user accounts option.

Comment: It would be helpful to go into detail regarding this process.

Comment: Actually, you can block other Microsoft accounts being added in Windows 8.1. For local user account, you'd better set up administrator account and log to your PC with this account each time. And Windows Eight Forum will help you. Sorry that I counld't leave a link, once warned but administator.